# jQuery click don't work in li:nth-child()

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to animate other `li:nth-child` but it doesn't work. So first I have

```
<li><a href="#"> H </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> A </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> B </a></li>
<li><a href="#"> C </a></li>
```

so first child will move the second child. This is the jquery but I don't know if this is right.

```
$('li:nth-child(1) a').click(function() {
   $('li:nth-child(2) a').animate({
      left: '100px',
   });
});
```

Here is my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Xenodo/g8xmts2d/5/)

Comment: Your `li:nth-child` code works fine - it's only the `left:` bit that's not working, as shown by adding another animation, eg `"font-size": '10px',`

Comment: then what should I exchange for 'left' to move it?

Comment: Add `li > a { position:relative; }` css (there's probably other/better ways, but this works in your fiddle)  **EDIT** Use `relative` to be relative to the `li`.  Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zrf0nsp8/

Comment: Do you have any source why it needs a position absolute? I'm such bad at this haha..anyway thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: No no i mean the connection between position relative and jquery animation

Comment: Without `position:relative`, the default is `position:static` which doesn't have a position for `a` elements.  From that link:  **static** *The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document. The top, right, bottom, left, and z-index properties **have no effect**. This is the default value.*

Comment: So you're changing the `left` property, be it with a fixed `.css("left", "100px")` or via your `.animate` and it has no effect either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Use `:nth-of-type` instead of `:nth-child` (`nth-child(2)` means you want to access the second child of `li` which is `null` as you only have one element)</strike>

The `left` property in animate won't do anything unless the `a` child has position absolute.

*css*

```
a {
  position: absolute;
}
```

*js*

```
$('li:nth-of-type(1) a').click(function(e) {
    $('li:nth-of-type(2) a').animate({
        left: '100px',
    });
});
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with OPs `:nth-child`, it works fine.  It's not `li :nth-child(2)` (there's no space to indicate child of `li`).   Sample in the question needs a `ul` wrapper.

Comment: @freedomn-m yep, you're right